# How to return an HttpResponse object instead of None

Tags: python-3.x, django, backend, web-deployment, web-deployment-project

can you help me out through this problem?, I'm a beginner and trying to learn django..even tho i tried so many other ways but it just wont work out. i hope you can help me

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import CharField , IntegerField, EmailField


class Member(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    email = models.EmailField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    password =  models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

**form.py**

```
from django.db.models import fields
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import Member



class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "age", "email", "password"]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import  render
from .models import Member
from .form import MemberForm
# Create your views here.




def join(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MemberForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, "HTML/join.html",{})

    else:
        form = MemberForm()
        return render(request, "HTML/join.html",{})
```

**error**

```
The view myapp.views.join didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: Hi Subhan, I would appreciate if u vote for the answers if they are relevant to your query or if u find helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is not valid, your view must return a response:

```
def join(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MemberForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, "HTML/join.html",{})
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=400) # Replace with what makes sense to you
    else:
        form = MemberForm()
        return render(request, "HTML/base.html", {})
```

In your urls write something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', join)
]
```

Note also that you should pass the form in the `context` parameter of `render` like: `render(request, "HTML/base.html", {'form': form})`.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/
as you can see in documents, render function's third parameter is context. you are passing argument as {}, blank dictionary.
you have to do something like this.

```
from django.shortcuts import  render
from .models import Member
from .form import MemberForm
# Create your views here.




def join(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MemberForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, "HTML/join.html",{})

    else:
        form = MemberForm()
        return render(request, "HTML/base.html",{'form':form})
```

In your Template

```
<form  method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```